# Count files in directories and put the results in 2 arraylists

Tags: java, android

I need to count files in directories, if a directory contains **more** then 1 (.apk) file it should be put in a separate (child) arraylist (userTypeList).

If a directory contains only 1 (.apk) file it should be put in a (parent) arraylist (ApkList).

The 2 arraylists will be used later in a **expandable** recyclerview.

If I check the log (count) shows 1 directory which contains more then 1 file so this works but I can`t get it to add the children in the arraylist (userTypeList).

It should access the code line: `else if (file.getName().endsWith(".apk") && count > 1)`
but it is skipped.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Output log:

> myapp.com.test E/FILECOUNT: 1
> myapp.com.test E/FILECOUNT: 2  <-- more then 1 file
> myapp.com.test E/FILECOUNT: 1
>
> myapp.com.test E/PARENTS: 16

Code:

```
private void getFileList(File parentDir) {
        int count = 0;
        Queue<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
        files.addAll(Arrays.asList(parentDir.listFiles()));

        while (!files.isEmpty()) {
            File file = files.remove();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
            
                //Check if directory includes more the 1 file
                count = file.list().length;
                Log.e("FILECOUNT", String.valueOf(count));
                files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));

                //Adding the children -- SKIPPED BY CODE
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".apk") && count > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    myDlChildModel = new MyDlChildModel();
                    ...
                    myDlChildModel.setImageId(info.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm));
                    myDlChildModel.setLabelName(info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                    myDlChildModel.setVersionName(info.versionName);
                    myDlChildModel.setPackagename(info.packageName);
                    userTypeList.add(i, myDlChildModel);
                }

                //Adding the parents
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".apk") && count == 1) {
                mydlModel = new MyDlModel();
                ...
                mydlModel.setImageId(info.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm));
                mydlModel.setLabelName(info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
                mydlModel.setVersionName(info.versionName);
                mydlModel.setPackagename(info.packageName);
                ApkList.add(mydlModel);
            }
        }

        if (userTypeList.size() > 0)
            Log.e("CHILDREN", String.valueOf(userTypeList.size()));
        if (ApkList.size() > 0)
            Log.e("PARENTS", String.valueOf(ApkList.size()));
    }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try to put count variable outside if condition

Change this line to outside if condition

```
 File file = files.remove();
//Check if directory includes more the 1 file
  count = file.list().length;
  Log.e("FILECOUNT", String.valueOf(count));
  if (file.isDirectory()) {

      files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));

      //Adding the children -- SKIPPED BY CODE
  }
```

Comment: Thx Munir but the app crashes then:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array (on line: countDirs = file.list().length;)

Comment: @Simon, then check for null before use. And dont use when null.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you assume that a single file exists in parentDir.listFiles(),
otherwise your if-else statement will not work.

Consider this example: 
2 folder under the parent directory:  P1 has 2 apk files, P2 has none.
your while loop looks like this

1) count =0; files = [P1,P2] file = P1,

is a directory, so :

2) count = 2; files = [P1, P2, apk1, apk2] file = P2,

also a directory, so:

3) **count = 0**, files =[P1,P2, apk1,apk2] file = apk1

since P2 went first, you have reset your counter, and apk will not pass the condition you have asked about.

To fix this, I suggest

1. Do not reuse "files"
2. Extract each part of your if statement to it's own method.
3. The logic of the first if-else statement (count > 1) should be called directly in the if statement, on each of the files in the directory, **not** after you have continued to iterate the original files.